# Using a keyword need to return the entire sentence that contains and remove that from dataset using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataset I need to find some certain keywords from the Review column and it needs to return the entire review from it.

For example, the sentence is like this: very nice product delivered.

The keyword I need to find is **nice**  and also I need to return the entire sentence that contains nice after that I need to remove the returned sentence from the dataset:

```
x = data.loc[data['Aspect'].str.match("product  quality") & (data['Sentence'].str.contains("nice|good|great|best"))]
data.drop([x],inplace=True)
```

How do it on pandas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do that.

```
pattern_to_remove = "(nice)|(good)|(great)|(best)"

row_filter = data['Sentence'].str.contains(patternDel) # a filter to determine if the row matches the pattern

data = data[~row_filter] # drop the rows
```